# Compare two dictionaries, remove key/value pair in one dict if it exists in the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates

I have two dictionaries. One looks like this:

```
dict1 = {'ana': 'http://ted.com', 'louise': 'http://reddit.com', 'sarah':'http://time.com'}
```

The other one looks like this:

```
dict2 = {'patricia': 'http://yahoo.com', 'ana': 'http://ted.com',
         'louise': 'http://reddit.com', 'florence': 'http://white.com'}
```

**I need to compare the two dictionaries, and eliminate from `dict2` any key/value pair already present in `dict1`**

As you can see, Ana and Louise already exist in `dict1`, so I'd like to automatically delete it from `dict2`
The output expected would contain **only** elements unique to `dict2` *and* not already present in `dict1`, and would look like:

```
dict2 = {'patricia': 'http://yahoo.com', 'florence': 'http://white.com'}
```

I don't need to do anything about Sarah being in `dict1`. I only care about comparing `dict2` with `dict1` to remove duplicates.

Extra info:

I tried to loop over the dicts in many different ways but it gave me two types of errors: `not hashable type` or `dict content changed during action`.

I also tried to make each into a list and combine the lists, but the end result is another list and I don't know how to turn a list back into a dictionary.

Comment: Do you care if both the key AND value are equal, or you only care about the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42287086/674039) removes items if the keys match.  I think you wanted to remove if both key **and** value matched.  This is actually very easy since you're using Python 3:

```
>>> dict(dict2.items() - dict1.items())
{'florence': 'http://white.com', 'patricia': 'http://yahoo.com'}
```

It works because `dict_items` objects treat subtraction operations as set differences.

Comment: Such simplicity and elegance. Wow. THANK YOU VERY MUCH, EVERYONE

Answer (score 1):

If any of you is looking for solution for python 2.x (because i was looking for), then here is the answer:

```
dict(filter(lambda x: x not in dict2.items(), dict1.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict2 = {i:j for i,j in dict2.items() if i not in dict1}
```

which results in `dict2` being:

```
{'florence': 'http://white.com', 'patricia': 'http://yahoo.com'}
```

An in-place solution could be:

```
for k in dict1:
    dict2.pop(k, None)
```

which yields a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

This simply looks for all the keys in dict1 that are in dict2 and then deletes the key/value pairs from dict2.

```
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2 and (dict1[key] == dict2[key]):
        del dict2[key]
```

Hoe this helps!